# How do I list custom taxonomy terms with the links?

Tags: customization, categories, taxonomy, links

I've the following code which gives the list of the portfolio category as text. What can I do to have them as links instead? thank you

```
  function thb_display_category_cus() {
  if ('portfolio' === get_post_type() ) {
    $categories = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio-category', '', ', ', '' );
    if ($categories !== '' && !empty($categories) ) {
        $categories = strip_tags($categories);
    }


 echo 

    esc_html($categories); 


      } else {
        the_category(', ' );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Take out your second "if" statement - the `strip_tags()` function is removing the links.

Comment: thanks. ok now I've that as result `<a href="https://yoursite.com/portfolio-category/test/" rel="tag">test</a>` (as pure text). How can I transform this in a hyperlink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebElain was correct but, you've also got the HTML escaped. The entire chunk of code should be:

```
  function thb_display_category_cus() {
  if ('portfolio' === get_post_type() ) {
    $categories = get_the_term_list( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio-category', '', ', ', '' );



 echo $categories


      } else {
        the_category(', ' );
      }
    }
```

Comment: perfect, thanks!